# DevExpress component Button for asp.net MVC onclick event is calling twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have the next issue. I'm using `ASP.NET MVC 4`, and `DevExpress` components. 
I have the button:

```
    @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
            {
                settings.Name = "LoginSubmit";
                settings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
                settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "LogIn";

            }).GetHtml()
```

When I click this button function LogIn is getting called twice.

But when I replace the DevExpress button extension with simple html all works fine, and function LogIn() getting called only once:

```
<button onclick="javascript:LogIn();" type="button">Enter</button>
```

Do any one have any workaround from this issue? Thx a lot for any advance.

Comment: Just my s cents....I have experienced similar issues with their controls and I've found that certain jQuery scripts or Bootstrap scripts clash with DevExpress (or the other way around).  Instead of loading my scripts in a partial file, I load them at the end of each file and exclude the conflicting script when using DevExpress controls.  It's a workaround for sure but it'll do for now.

Comment: Thanks for your notice. I think it can be helpfull for people who use DevExpress for asp.net MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was waiting for a long time for an answer and found a lot of other bugs, and decided that `DevExpress` for `ASP.NET MVC` is still not stable. So I dont recommend to use it in enteprise  `ASP.NET MVC` application!

**EDITED**

After the new release of DevExpress this bug can be fixed like this:

```
settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(){LogIn();}";
```

Hope it can be helpfull